# Como hacer una matriz en pascal con filas y columnas que decide el usuario?

Tags: pascal

Has ahora este es mi avance pero me da error ...

```
program matriz;

uses crt;

var
    filas, columnas : integer;
    esCuadrada : boolean;

procedure Encabezado();
begin
    clrscr;
    write('Elaborado por : ');
    textcolor(green);
    writeln('');
    textcolor(white);
    write('Pulse enter para empezar con el programa ...');
    readln();
end;

procedure CalculoMatriz(filas : integer; columnas : integer);
var
    matrix : array[1...filas, 1...columnas] of integer;
    i,a : integer;
begin
    for i:=0 to filas do
        begin
            for a:=0 to columnas do
                begin
                    write('Introduce el elemento [',i,'][',a,']');
                    readln(matrix[i,a]);
                end;
        end;
end;


begin
    Encabezado();
    esCuadrada := false;
    while (not esCuadrada) do
        begin
            clrscr;
            write('Introduce la cantidad de filas de la matriz : ');
            readln(filas);
            write('Introduce la cantidad de columnas de la matriz : ');
            readln(columnas);
            if (filas =  columnas) then
                esCuadrada := true
            else
                begin
                    clrscr;
                    write('La matriz');
                    textcolor(red);
                    write(' no es cuadrada ');
                    textcolor(white);
                    write(', presiona enter para intentalo de nuevo ...');
                    readln();
                end;
        end;
    CalculoMatriz(filas, columnas);

end.
```

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: Qué compilador utilizas? Pregunto porque la respuesta puede ser distinta para Delphi, que para FreePascal, que para TurboPascal, por mencionar algunos ejemplos. Sugiero también indicar cuál es el error que estás observando, ya que el código por si mismo puede que no lo haga evidente y usualmente alguien va a intentar responder sin compilar y/o ejecutar el código.

Answer (score -1):

Hay varios errores en tu código que debes ir corrigiendo antes de avanzar y poder llegar a obtener el resultado que deseas.

Por lo pronto la definición de la matriz es incorrecta; Aquí se puede probar y revisar los errores (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler).

```
procedure CalculoMatriz(filas : integer; columnas : integer);
var
    matrix : array[1...filas, 1...columnas] of integer;
    i,a : integer;
```

Puedes ir corrigiendo (***y editando la pregunta original***).

- En la definición del array utilizar 2 puntos en lugar de tres, para definir los límites.
- Para definir el límite superior de una variable (matriz) debes utilizar una constante, no puedes hacerlo utilizando un parámetro del procedimiento.

Con eso desaparecerán estos errores:

```
main.pas(26,23) Error: Illegal expression
main.pas(26,24) Error: Can't evaluate constant expression
main.pas(26,24) Fatal: Syntax error, "]" expected but "identifier NFILAS" found
```

Si corriges eso y añades un punto al final (que también falta), verás que el programa ejecuta y te empieza a solicitar datos.